# MVVM - WPF How do i bind my View to my Viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, model-binding

I have my View called "FahrgemeinschaftenView.xaml" & my ViewModel "Fahrgemeinschaften.cs."
So by default the View is bound to its own cs, which in this case would be "FahrgemeinschaftenView.xaml.cs".
Im very new to MVVM, but it says the ModelViewlayer should contain all the logic. So i try to connect "FahrgemeinschaftenView.xaml" with "FahrgemeinschaftenViewModel.cs", but wasn`t able to figure out how do to that (Passing Data).

[image: MVVM View to ViewModel Problem]

Comment: The connection between `Foo.xaml` and `Foo.xaml.cs` it not a binding (in the sense of WPF/MVVM data binding). The latter is just the "code behind" file of the former (where generated elements like `x:Name` fields and event handler methods reside). Passing a view model to a view is typically accomplished by assigning an instance of the view model class to the `DataContext` property of the view. All Bindings in the view that do not have an explicitly set source object will use the DataContext object as their source.

Comment: We will need to see your code to know how to help you. Without the code, we have no idea what you have already tried or what the problem with your current approach is. Please note that code should be edited into your question in a code block.

Comment: Also note that code is generally hard to read when you mix languages in your identifier names. Better call it Carpool instead of Fahrgemeinschaft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view (in this case **FahrgemeinschaftenView**) has a property named **DataContext**. The simplest way of binding your view to your ViewModel is setting an instance of **FahrgemeinschaftenViewModel** to the **DataContext** property on your view.

You can do this in your constructor in **FahrgemeinschaftenView.xaml.cs**.
Just write:

```
DataContext = new FahrgemeinschaftenViewModel();
```

right under the call to InitializeComponent()

```
public FahrgemeinschaftenView()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = new FahrgemeinschaftenViewModel();
}
```